# using scipy.optimize.brute for trained model

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, scipy

Trying to find an optimal value using scipy.optimize.brute.
One of the features of the trained model takes a value between 0 and 55.

I need to find at what value this feature should be assigned for getting predicted value closest to 900. Can someone help me with python code?

```
from scipy import optimize
target_temper = 900 # Оптимальная температура
x_range = (0, 55)

def predictor(x):
    a=xg_reg.predict(x) - target_temper
    return np.abs(a)

resbrute = optimize.brute(predictor, x_range, full_output=True, finish=optimize.fmin)

...
```

Comment: What does your code output ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure out the solution!

```
target_temper = 953 # The optimal value 
x_col_name = 'Навеска фторида, кг(t)' # The variable for which I need to iterate over the values from 0 to 66
x_range = (0, 66)
x_step = 0.5
rrange = (slice(x_range[0], x_range[1], x_step),)

def predictor(n):
    data_line = X.tail(1)
    data_line[variable_column_name] = n
    a=xg_reg.predict(data_line) - target_temper
    return np.abs(a)

resbrute = optimize.brute(predictor, rrange,  full_output=True, finish=optimize.fmin)
optimal_value = resbrute[0]
```